# jQuery UI: DatePicker, select only today's date through past

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the datePicker in the jQuery UI core. I need a date picker that can only pick dates through the past all the way to today.

Is there an easy way to do this?  -- Note I'm using the UI core, not the DatePicker Plugin.

My jQuery call:

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should use the maxDate option when initializing the datepicker:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ maxDate: '0' });
```

look here for reference: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-maxDate