# How to show just current date in calender?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a code of calender in java script. Its in working, want it to automaticaly select current date .its Possible.

Javascript code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#interview_on" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Custom Form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/interviewvalue/" class="form-horizontal" id="userform" name="uform" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="control-group formSep">
    <label for="u_fname" class="control-label">Interview On</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="interviewon" id="interview_on" readonly="true" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <button class="btn btn-gebo" type="submit" name="asubmit">Submit</button>
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-gebo" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you loaded jQuery and jQuery Ui libs..?

Comment: you can make other days of month inactive using datepicker property. checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033319/jquery-ui-datepicker-select-only-todays-date-through-past this may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the actual field to be filled with the current date just use the setDate after creating the datepicker. Like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#interview_on").datepicker();
        $("#interview_on").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    });
</script>
```

In case you want to restrict the selectable dates to only today, Tobo's suggestion is correct, just do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#interview_on").datepicker({minDate: 0, maxDate: 0});
        $("#interview_on").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the selectable range of the Datepicker like this

```
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    minDate: -10D, maxDate: "+10D" 
 });
```

which shows 10 days of the past and 10 days of the future.

You find a detailed description here http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max